# How do I open a jQuery popupWindow with a URL from an html tag attribute?

Tags: jquery, popup

I'm working with this jQuery plugin: http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html which seems great.  My jQuery code is attached to table rows in an inventory table and looks like this:

```
$("tr").popupWindow({windowURL:$(this).attr("url"),windowName:'Details', centerScreen: true});
```

And the HTML (from PHP) looks like this:

```
echo "<tr url=\"details.php?id=$idNum\"><td>$idNum</td>";
```

For whatever reason the expression $(this).attr("url") is coming up as undefined.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT 1: Perhaps this is related to the this keyword and is a scope issue?

EDIT 2: I decided to move the jQuery code from  into a  next to each   This seems like a terrible solution but it bypasses any scoping issues and works.  It now looks like this:

```
echo "<tr id=\"$idNum\"><td>$idNum</td>";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $('#$idNum').popupWindow({
    windowURL:'details.php?tag=$idNum'
    });</script>";
```

Thanks for helping me look for the right solution....  if I eventually discover it I'll come back and update this, but for now the kludge will stand.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create non-standard attributes. Use HTML5's `data-` attributes, which were made for storing stuff:

```
$("tr").popupWindow({windowURL:$(this).data("url"),windowName:'Details', centerScreen: true});
```

And change your PHP:

```
echo "<tr data-url=\"details.php?id=$idNum\"><td>$idNum</td>";
```

Comment: Ok, good tip on the html5 data attributes, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: It should. Check your other jQuery. Also, try iterating over all of the `<tr>` elements with a `.each` loop and see if using that will help. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not sure.  I got no errors just a blank popup (ie windowURL was undefined).  I still think it was some kind of scoping issue.  I'll update my original post with my kludge solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code provided, the context in which "this" is being called cannot be determined with certainty. You're definitely trying to use it to refer to a DOM element, but it is returning "undefined", because whatever "this" is actually referring to does not have the "url" attribute. If you assign a class or ID to an A tag, you might have a little more success...

Here's some modified HTML (from PHP):

```
echo "<tr><td><a id=\"$idNum\" href=\"details.php?id=$idNum\">$idNum</a></td>";
```

And here's your jQuery code:

```
$("#myRow").popupWindow({windowURL:$("#" + $idNum).attr("href"),windowName:'Details', centerScreen: true});
```

I haven't tested it, but I think this'll work for you.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: using the id would work with a specific element, but I have 509 rows in the table and I need it to work with all of them.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  Again I think this is because the $idNum in a scope inaccessible from the jQuery in my <head>.  I'm updating the original post with my eventual solution that bypassed the scoping issue (and is a total kludge)